# How to show image from url in excel sheet(2003)

Tags: image, excel, excel-2003, imageurl, vba

How to write  a macro for displaying 
image from url which I have in one 
of the cell in excel 2003.

Can anybody help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you want to display this picture, in web browser or in Excel sheet??

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent question about this that also asked about re-sizing to fit within a cell.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15589423/1467082

Here are the 4 lines of code that you need to get started:

```
Sub InsertPicFromURL()

Dim pic As String 'file path of pic
Dim myPicture As Picture 'embedded pic

pic = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4d3ac4ebeddcf958a7b8d3e73c2c6805?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"
Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic)

End Sub
```