# How can I insert pictures into my Excel workbok from a list of URLs?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook (Excel 2013, Windows 10) containing a column of paths to jpg files on my computer (column "B") and I'd like to have a macro which will work through all of the rows inserting a thumbnail of the picture into the cell to the left of the path, ie in column "A".

I'm no macro VBA coder and usually record macros close to what I want and then edit the code it records for me. So I know that I can write a macro which simply records me doing this and the macro runs. However when I try to generalise it, I get an error, although the error is on the same line as ran fine previously.

So, this macro works -

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("D:\My Documents HDD\...(path)...\Filename.jpg").Select
End Sub
```

However this doesn't work -

```
Sub Insert_picture_from_URL()
'
' Insert_picture_from_URL Macro
'
    Dim i As Long, v As String, w As String
        For i = 1 To 200
            v = ("B" & i)
            w = ("A" & i)
            Range(w).Select
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(v).Select
        Next i
End Sub
```

I get "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Insert property of the Pictures class"

Please can you tell me where I'm going wrong? I realise I'll need to add code to resize the thumbnails to a reasonable size, but I need to get this to work first.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting an Online Picture to Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113876/inserting-an-online-picture-to-excel-with-vba).

Comment: `v = ("B" & i)` - so `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(v)`.... is equivalent to `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("B1")`, `"B2"` and so on. `"B1"` is not a reference to a `Range`, but `Range("B1")` is.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Sub Insert_picture_from_URL()
'
' Insert_picture_from_URL Macro
'
    Dim i As Long, v As String, w As String
        For i = 1 To 200
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Cells(i, 2).Value)
                .Top = Cells(i, 1).Top
                .Left = Cells(i, 1).Left
            End With
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the error "Run-time error 1004. Unable to get the Insert property of the Pictures class" as before.

Comment: I've followed the link at the top of this question and the code there work well enough for me to modify for my need. Thanks, I did search before posting but failed to find that answer.