# How to import images stored as Blobs (in .NET domain) to an Excel Workbook?

Tags: .net, excel, vba

I am currently importing specific job information from a .NET database to an excel workbook. These jobs often include images which are stored as BLOB files.

As of yet, I've only been able to import these images to an Excel Workbook using this macro (https://www.exceltip.com/general-topics-in-vba/insert-pictures-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html) combined with Google's URL shortener. However, this tool is now out of action and other URL shorteners don't seem to work.

I'm thinking that there must be an alternative solution to achieving this (using VBA). Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's unclear what the actual problem is here - you mention ".NET database" but that doesn't really tell us anything.  You're using a URL shortener - why exactly ? What happened when you didn't use that?  What do your URL's look like?  Is the (presumably) website a public-facing one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890281/excel-convert-url-to-images-1004 It's essentially the same issue here. Almost identical, however, that solution is not viable. It's an online app which imports data to an excel template (client-side) so of course flagging it for later review is not an option. By shortening the URL which was discovered through trial and error, it fixed the problem. However, now google has discontinued their URL shortener tool, it's no longer possible.

Comment: That looks only broadly related to the problem you're having - it seems like the root cause was not even really determined.  Might need more information to make any useful suggestions as to what to try next.